# remember me option in GAE python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am working on a project in which i am working on a signup/login module. I have implemented the sessions in webapp2 python successfully. Now i want to implement the remember me feature on login. I am unable to find anything which can help me. I do know that i have to set the age of session. But i do not know how. Here is my session code.

```
def dispatch(self):

    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
        # Dispatch the request.
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
        # Save all sessions.
        self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

@webapp2.cached_property
def session(self):
    # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
    return self.session_store.get_session()
```

Config:

```
config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {
    'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',
}
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in case you don't know the difference between sessions and cookies

> What is a **Cookie**? A cookie is a small piece of text stored on a
>   user's computer by their browser. Common uses for cookies are
>   authentication, storing of site preferences, shopping cart items, and
>   server session identification.
>
> Each time the users' web browser interacts with a web server it will
>   pass the cookie information to the web server. Only the cookies stored
>   by the browser that relate to the domain in the requested URL will be
>   sent to the server. This means that cookies that relate to
>   www.example.com will not be sent to www.exampledomain.com.
>
> In essence, a cookie is a great way of linking one page to the next
>   for a user's interaction with a web site or web application.

.

> What is a **Session**? A session can be defined as a server-side storage of
>   information that is desired to persist throughout the user's
>   interaction with the web site or web application.
>
> Instead of storing large and constantly changing information via
>   cookies in the user's browser, only a unique identifier is stored on
>   the client side (called a "session id"). This session id is passed to
>   the web server every time the browser makes an HTTP request (ie a page
>   link or AJAX request). The web application pairs this session id with
>   it's internal database and retrieves the stored variables for use by
>   the requested page.

If you want to implement something like "remember me" you should use cookies because data stored in session isn't persistent.

For setting and getting cookies in `webapp2`:

```
response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'remember_me=%s' % some_hash)

request.cookies.get('remember_me', '')
```

I strongly recommend you to read this [article](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs253/unit-4) that has explained this stuff thoroughly.

Comment: How can i set its expire duration.

Comment: According to article I mentioned in answer: `Set-Cookie: user = 123; Expires = Tue, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share the code. Because i am unable to find the code there.

Comment: `response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'remember_me=%s; Expires = Tue, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT' % some_hash)`

Comment: Can i provide a time duration like 36000 sec

Comment: Your response will be really appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age You can't directly set expire date to something like 36000 sec later, if you want to do that you should generate that date. That would be a completely different question which you can find its answer by searching.